# Will a standard 9V alkaline battery (300mAh- 400mAH) be able to supply 2.5A for 5-10 second at a time?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacity

For example, I have a motor that needs a surge of 2.5A for a short amount of time from a 6V power supply.

Will any 6V battery able to supply that current? Even if let's say it has only a 500mAH. How does AMP rating matter when talking about this?

Comment: The DCR of the motor must be much higher than ESR of the battery . A 9V cell is higher. What is the motor DCR? And battery ESR=Voc/Isc

Comment: Do you mean "9V battery" (i.e, PP3) in your question, or some other type of battery? If the latter, what kind?

Comment: related (if not duplicate): [Battery Ampere-hour rating vs Battery Amps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/122734/7036)

Comment: Conventionally you'd want a battery rated for high discharge current.  However, particularly if you can *anticipate* the need, you may be able to do something with capacitors that you charge up slowly to deliver a brief current pulse.

Comment: a 9V battery is made from six AAAA cells .... it has a lot of internal resistance .... it does not produce much current as a result

Comment: 2-5A into a short circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use rechargeable NiMH batteries instead of alkaline cells.

This [Energizer AA NiMH cell](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nh15-2300.pdf) is specified for 4.6A continuous discharge current, for example - way more than typical alkaline cells can provide. It'll probably provide even more current for a few seconds. Plus, you can recharge it!

Five of those in series and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

For a common 9 volt battery - almost certainly not

4 AA alkaline cells (6 volts) - possibly

4 C alkaline cells (6 volts) - much more likely (although I've seen some C cells that have the same specs as AA cells)